# What is _() in a Python dictionary?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

This might be a dumb question but I recently stumbled upon this code in Django Rest Framework, couldn't find out what is the _() inside that dictionary...

```
class SlugField(CharField):
    default_error_messages = {
        'invalid': _('Enter a valid "slug" consisting of letters, numbers, underscores or hyphens.'),
        'invalid_unicode': _('Enter a valid "slug" consisting of Unicode letters, numbers, underscores, or hyphens.')
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the purpose of the single underscore “_” variable in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893163/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-single-underscore-variable-in-python)

Comment: `_` is just a variable, like any other, e.g. `x`.`_()` calls the object being referred to by that variable, it's probably a function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the purpose of the single underscore "\_" variable in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893163/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-single-underscore-variable-in-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

somewhere before your code you definitely can see something like this:

```
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
```

so that the variable "_" stands for an imported function, in that case this is translation app.

See [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/translation/#internationalization-in-python-code).

Comment: In your code example the `_` doesn't stand for an imported library but for a function.

Comment: yeap, thanks, have edited.